# How to change struct properties in Swift

Tags: swift-playground, swift5, ipad-playgrounds

I’m trying out Swift playgrounds and I cannot find a way to change value of a struct. Below I want to change properties of Shadow from default values.

I’ve tried the initialiser and dot syntax but I get ‘field is inaccessible due to internal protection level.

```
let circle = Circle()
circle.draggable = true
//var shadow = Shadow(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411764705882, green: 0.6862745098039216, blue: 0.13333333333333333, alpha: 1.0), offset: Point(3,-3), blurRadius: 5, opacity: 1)
var shadow = Shadow()
shadow.color = .red
circle.dropShadow = shadow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re apparently using the “Shapes” playground.

So, view the source by clicking on “...” » “Advanced” » “View Auxiliary Source Files” » “Contents” » “Modules” » “Book.playgroundmodule” » “Sources” » “PlaygroundAPI”.

If you look at the `Shadow` struct, none of those properties are declared as `public`. That means that you don’t have access to them outside of that module.

In contrast, if you look at the `Circle` declaration in contrast, `radius` is public. And if you look at `AbstractDrawable`, `dropShadow` is `public`, too.

In the absence of an explicit access qualifier (e.g., `public`), a property gets the `internal` access qualifier, only accessible within that module. (See [The Swift Programming Language: Access Control](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html).) And your code in that playground is not within the same module as where `Shadow` was defined. Thus you don’t have access to it.

So, bottom line, your warning is just telling you that you cannot access this internal property of the `Shadow` `struct`.

---

This begs the question as to why they declared `Shadow` such that you can’t customize the nature of the shadow. I suspect it is just an oversight on their part. For example, I opened up this playground workbook in Xcode and replaced the `init` method for `Shadow` with the following:

```
public init(offset: Point = Point(x: 1, y: -1), blurRadius: Double = 1, opacity: Double = 0.3, color: Color = .black) {
    self.offset = offset
    self.blurRadius = blurRadius
    self.opacity = opacity
    self.color = color
}
```

Then I could reopen this playground on my iPad and do things like:

```
let circle = Circle(radius: 30)
circle.dropShadow = Shadow(opacity: 0.9, color: .green)
```

And that yielded:

[image: big circle green shadow]

Comment: Hmm.. wow. Can't believe they would mess up something so obvious. Should this be reported to "Apple - The Most Innovative Privacy-Concerned Company on the Planet"? About viewing the source, is that on Xcode on PC? Bcz I was working on the iPad and don't know how to follow that. I assume the same for "the playground workbook"; you can only edit that on PC?

Comment: You can *view* the source right on the iPad (by tapping the “...” button and the subsequent menu items shown in my answer above). But to *edit* the extra source files buried within that playground, I had to do that on my Mac, opening up the the playground sitting in my iCloud Drive (when I create playgrounds on the iPad, they’re saved in iCloud, which I can then open in macOS).